# Android mobile ads ANR

Tags: android, admob

I have call mobile ads initialize with open ads [AdMob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdMob), but sometimes, it is [ANR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANR#Technology) in some devices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This ANR is most likely not caused by an error that you've made; rather, it lies in AdMob's implementation. Thus, you're probably out of luck if you want to fix it yourself. However, you can make sure you're using the latest version of the AdMob SDK which possibly fixes this error (or, if it doesn't, try temporarily downgrading instead if it worked OK previously).

Comment: Well, they don't fail at first but when I use admod open app ads. Currently, if i remove open ads, not ANR. :( so sad.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74355813/edit). Thanks in advance.